# Cannot connect with device using meteor build

Tags: android, meteor

I am getting the following error when running `meteor run android-device`:

```
Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:
   Error: Command failed:                     
   /home/user/git_repo/educore/_lms/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run
   --device
   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute
   android:font
   ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute
   android:fontStyle
   ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute
   android:fontVariationSettings
   ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute
   android:fontWeight
   ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute
   android:ttcIndex


   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * What went wrong:
   Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

What could be causing it? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after add these plugins:
cordova-android-support-gradle-release@1.4.3 and add code and
cordova-android@6
then add npm package
npm install xml2js

and run the project
then remove then cordova-android@6
Change version cordova-android-support-gradle-release@1.2.0
delete coordova build folder from local
then run the project issue was fixed